# Running Active Batch 8 client with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Can you run Active Batch 8 on windows XP?  I have checked the vendors site and did not find a requirements sheet. We currently run the client on WIN7.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Haven't tried it, don't have an XP machine readily available to me.  Could do it in a VM, but thought I would ask first.

Comment: Did you check with [ASCI](http://www.advsyscon.com/home/company/contacts.aspx?section=email)?

Comment: I checked their website, the datasheets and whitepapers.  I could not find said information.  I have not contacted them directly no.

Comment: After you have tried to run thr program yourself we might be able to help.  There might not even be a problem.  You are expected to research a problem before you ask for help.

Comment: Agreed, I should research my problem first.  Which I did, I think it is obvious I am not on here asking for help with my homework.  I can and am in the process of setting up a VM to test this.  I did not just ask the question without first looking for the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run Active Batch Admin on windows XP.  You can run it on the following OS's : Windows 7, Vista, Xp, Server 2008 R2, 2008 and 2003. You must have Dot net 3.5 for this application to run successfully.